# How to share standalone Android Wear App for testing?

Tags: android, wear-os

**What i am trying :**

I am new to the WearOS development. I am trying to create standalone app (for 1.x and 2.0) and share it for testing.

As I mentioned standalone app, it's not dependent on any mobile devices, neither Android or Apple phone.

**What i have tried :**

I have tried releasing an app to PlayStore as an "Internal test" and as a tester, I tried to install the app by web PlayStore install button. The PlayStore shows "... will be installed on your device soon". But still, it's not installing the app. My wear is connected to the internet but no luck.

**Manifest Entry:**

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"/>
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
     android:value="true" />

<uses-library
     android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
     android:required="false"/>
```

**Question :**

Is companion app is needed for standalone wear app? OR may be if you know and can share any suggestions to share standalone wear app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From WearOS 2.0, PlayStore is available on wear. So, When we open app page on PlayStore and install from there by selecting wear device, wear 2.0 devices are able to get the app directly through the PlayStore without companion app.